# The .addClass() doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery

On my first project ever, I'm trying to combine **.hover** with **.addClass()** to highlight the div under the mouse pointer.

It should be fairly simple, but i can't get it to work, here's what i wrote so far:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#NewItem').hover(function() {        
        $('#NewItem').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**css**

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#NewItem {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    Width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}

.active {
    background-color:#556677;
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
         <div id="NewItem">             
            <p> Add item </p>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Trying to find out what i got wrong i switched ".addclass('active')" with ".hide()" and it did make the div disapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does add the class on hover. The problem is that the selector `#NewItem` is more specific than the selector `.active`, which means that the background color added with the `.active` selector is being overridden.

The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of `#NewItem` is 0, 1, 0, 0; while the specifity of `.active` is 0, 0, 1, 0.

Increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the `.active` selector, and read more about [specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/oynq3Lx3/)

```
#NewItem.active {
  background-color: #556677;
}
```

As a side note, *if* you intended to toggle the class on mouseenter and mouseout, use probably want to use the `.toggleClass()` method instead:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ztjmqjby/)

```
$('#NewItem').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

or just avoid jQuery completely and use the `:hover` pseudo-class (if that works in your case):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/np2hq976/)

```css
#NewItem:hover {
  background-color: #556677;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `class` is added, you will not get the desired result. The reason is CSS specificity. So change it this way:

```css
#NewItem.active {
  background-color: #556677;
}
```

The `#id` takes more precedence over the `.class` selector. So giving both will work.

For [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), use this as reference:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The background-color of your NewItem ID overrides the background-color of the class active, because of CSS specificity. See your new, working example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".newItem").hover(function(){
      $(".newItem").toggleClass("active"); 
  });

});
```

```css
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.newItem {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    Width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}

.active {
    background-color:#556677;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

        <div id="background">
             <div class="newItem">             
                <p> Add item </p>
             </div>
        </div>
</body>
```